# Community Ad Feature Request

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to have a post with all the sandbox of ads that this site has cause they are useful and just searching them up year by year is quite hard? This is a more feature request about the community promotion ads.

Comment: Sounds like a job for *tags*. See [meta-tag:community-ads].